# Events handling in GWT

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I want to do something like this:
I want a cell table in which each cell is a class which I have written. I need to add a click event for the cell table. So How can I get which cell was clicked. As Cell is a class which I have defined, based on the clicked cell I need to perform some action. Can I somehow get the object details of the cell which was clicked. For e.g

I need a excel sheet which is like cell table, each cell in the excel sheet is a class I have defined, say the class holds the values like:

```
CellClass{
 boolean isempty;
 string name;
 int id;
}
```

Now If i click in the excel sheet, how can I get which cell was clicked, so that I can tell user the name of the cell and whether it is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use ClickableTextCell to make clickable cell. Refer below Code detail:

```
nameCell = new ClickableTextCell() {
            @Override
            public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
                    String data, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
                super.render(context, "", sb);

                    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<input type=text value='"+data+"' />);

        };

        nameColumn = new Column<Document, String>(nameCell) {

            @Override
            public String getValue(Document object) {
                //code
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is only one instance of a Cell for each Column, not every value is represented by a Cell instance. The structure you describe above would be the structure of the data you set in CellTable.setRowData.

A Cell has to declare the events it's interested in, via the super constructor in [AbstractCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractCell.html) or the `getConsumedEvents` method defined in [Cell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractCell.html). In your case the "click" event.

You can then implement the `onBrowserEvent` method in your custom cell and react to the click. A context will be passed to this method indicating which row and column the event refers to (see [Cell.Context](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/cell/client/Cell.Context.html)) as well as the key and value associated with the click.

In your case, the custom Cell would look something like this:

```
public class MyCell extends AbstractCell<String> {
    public MyCell() {
        super("click");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        // Handle the click event.
        if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
            // Ignore clicks that occur outside of the outermost element.
            EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
            if (parent.getFirstChildElement().isOrHasChild(Element.as(eventTarget))) {
                doAction(value, valueUpdater);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also intercept the event at the [Column](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Column.html) level.

You can find more information in the [Dev Guide](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells#cell-onBrowserEvent)